structure of mkdocs material translation
While I read through the docs, I saw the section about translation:
https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/setup/changing-the-language/#site-language-selector
While they describe how to configure it in mkdocs.yml I am missing some information about directory structure.
I know I could use i18n plugin, but we are not planning to support Asian language.
What I have in mind is something like this:
.
├── docs
│   ├── de
│   │   ├── special
│   │   │   └── page.md
│   │   └── index.md
│   ├── en
│   │   ├── special
│   │   │   └── page.md
│   │   └── index.md
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── extra.css
└── mkdocs.yml

But this always leads to a 404 page and the navigation still shows "DE" and "En" instead of "index" and "special".
What do I need to change, and why is the documentation missing out?
